# Hibernate Criteria setFetchMod as join is ignored

Tags: hibernate, criteria

In my hbm i have:

```
  < set name="products" lazy="true" cascade="none" table="product">
                <key>
                    <column name="PRODUCT_ID" not-null="true" />
                </key>
                <many-to-many column="SHOP_ID" class="Shop" />
            </set>
```

with a criteria query:

```
    Criteria criteria = createCriteria(getBusinessClass());
     ...
    List list  = criteria.setFetchMode("products", FetchMode.JOIN).list()
```

Even when there is fetchmode: **JOIN**, hibernate still fires separate SQL queries to fetch products and not as a join !

Comment: try to change lazy to false...

Comment: sometimes I don't need to get the full objects Product.

Comment: I think that when the fetch type is lazy, hibernate fetches only the products you access at the moment one by one, not the whole list... It's just a guess...

Comment: What is your question? Looks like hibernate is doing what it is supposed to do. If you specify join, the products will be pulled, because it is the only chance it can do a join on the products. remove the join if I understand that you need to lazy load the products.

Comment: @neila Take a look at this http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-fetching-strategies-examples/